# Problems with column user_id is not unique

Tags: django

I had such a problem here, when I ask a question he does not save and this error pops up: "Django: IntegrityError: column user_id is not unique". Tell me what the problem is.

Here my models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=False, auto_now_add=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=240, blank=True)
    tag = TaggableManager()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.date_added = date.today()

        if self.title and not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        super(Question, self).save(**kwargs)
```

views.py

```
def ask(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            question = form.save(commit=False)
            question.user = request.user
            question.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return redirect('/question/one_question/' + str(question.id))
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Traceback

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError at /question/ask/
Exception Value: column user_id is not unique
```

Comment: Why is this a surprise to you? You have a OneToOneField from Question to User, which means that each User is only allowed *one* question. Adding any more will lead to the error you see.

Comment: The way you have setup your model, a user can only ask one question - so after they asked the first question, you cannot add any more `Question`s for that user. Is this what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your **Question** model, as @DanielRoseman says you should change the *OneToOneField* you're using:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    # ... ... .. other fields .... ....
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
```

You need to change from **OneToOneField** to **ForeignKey** in case that one question can be related **only** with one user but an user can be related with **more than one** question (Many to one relation):

```
class Question(models.Model):
    # ... ... .. other fields .... ....    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

or probably **ManyToManyField** is the most apropiated here, in case that **many** answers can be related with **many** users:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    # ... ... .. other fields .... ....
    user = models.ManyToMany(User)
```