# Django Error :: IntegrityError Exception Value: column user_id is not unique

Tags: django, postgresql

> IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '/fixtures/orders.yaml':
> Could not load customers.Customer(pk=56195): column user_id is not
> unique

Here is my model

```
class Customer(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField (User, unique=True)
```

I have generated the fixtures by using django fixture command and run the testcases , When running by using below command

```
./manage.py test orders.tests.FixturesTestFixturesTest
```

I am getting below error ,

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
*************
(<Customer: AnonymousUser>, True)
****************
Checking permissions: (['Can view profile', 'Can change profile', 'Can delete profile'], [], [])
*************
(<Customer: jeffrey.gulan>, True)
****************
Checking permissions: ([], [<User: jeffrey.gulan>, <User: jeffrey.gulan>, <User: jeffrey.gulan>, <User: jeffrey.gulan>, <User: jeffrey.gulan>], [])
E
======================================================================
ERROR: setUpClass (orders.tests.FixturesTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Desktop/env_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 952, in setUpClass
    'database': db_name,
  File "/Desktop/env_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Desktop/env_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 318, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture  
    '/Desktop/env_app/projectname/apps/orders/fixtures/orders.yaml':
    Could not load customers.Customer(pk=56195): column user_id is not unique
```

I have tried with below links also,

> [column user_id is not unique, with Django UserProfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086578/column-user-id-is-not-unique-with-django-userprofiles)
>
> [Problems with column user_id is not unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831791/problems-with-column-user-id-is-not-unique)

But I didn't get proper solution.

Would be really nice if I could get some Help!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Check your `/fixtures/orders.yaml` file. Does it contain two customers with `user_id=56195`?